# CartThrob - Quote instead of payment

Tags: expresso-store, cartthrob, ecommerce, brilliantretail

A client of mine is wanting to enable Ecommerce at some point but in the interim for at least the next 12 months they would like a request a quote feature. I was thinking that it would make the most sense to use something like CartThrob, Brilliant Retail or Espresso in which customers can add products to their basket (probably will rename it to get a quote) for which they can then submit to our client's sales team.

However instead of going through a typical payment gateway process we just send the sales team an email.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Appreciate you looking at this,
Adeeb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with CartThrob. It has a single-page check out feature that gives you the flexibility to completely abandon the 'Cart' metaphor... Then you could combine that with Off-line payment to skip the need for a payment processor.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly do this with Cartthrob but just to add another option you could also do it with something like [RememberMe](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/remember-me) to build an "enquiry list" and then feed the list into a form field and send an email (perhaps using Freeform).

Comment: That's great to know thanks for pointing out an option which doesn't require a full blown Ecommerce rollout.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do this with BrilliantRetail as well. You could simply remove the product pricing tags from the page templates and email templates and display only the product titles, options, etc.